# schema.org / Product - property to store industry standards

Tags: schema, product, schema.org, microdata

what is the best place in a [Product] to attach information about achieved/fulfilled industry standards e.g. DIN norm, fire resistance class and stuff like that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the product. For medical devices, https://schema.org/legalStatus would be appropriate.

For other things, I think https://schema.org/PropertyValue is probably the most appropriate.